# How can I rsync a set of subdirectories?

Tags: rsync

I have a source directory that looks like the following (with numerous subdirectories inside of the src and bin dirs):

- top_dir

  - proj1

    - src/
    - bin/
    - scripts/
    - somefile.txt
  - proj2

    - src/
    - bin/
    - target

      - bin/
    - file.xml

I'd like to rsync just the bin dirs directly under the project directories (i.e., ignore top_dir/proj2/target/bin/) and their contents to the destination directory, so that it looks like this:

- top_dir

  - proj1

    - bin
  - proj2

    - bin

I could probably make it work by explicitly listing out each bin directory (there are about 15 in my real scenario) in an include-from file, but I was thinking there must be a way to say that I want to sync all the top_dir/*/bin directories.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Possibility 1

Using the shell expansion<sup>1</sup>  instead of `rsync`'s filter rules, you can do as follows:

a. To include all `bin` dirs in the `top_dir` hierarchy:

```
rsync -av -R top_dir/**/bin/ destination_path
```

Here `-R` is a rsync<sup>2</sup> parameter standing for *relative*. `man rsync` explains it as

> Use relative paths.  This means that the full path names specified on the command line are sent  to  the server  rather  than just the last parts of the filenames.  This is particularly useful when you want to send several different directories at the same time.

but in essence it means that the directory structure is preserved.

`**` is a shell globbing pattern and searches recursively for directories named `bin` under `top_dir`. So with the above example the command line gets expanded to:

```
rsync -av -R top_dir/proj1/bin/ top_dir/proj2/bin/ destination_path
```

b. If you only want to include `bin` dirs one level below the project dir, just use a single `*` (that works with "ancient" shells too!):

```
rsync -av -R top_dir/*/bin/ destination_path
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You need a recent *bash* version (>4) and activate recursive globbing via `shopts -s globstar`. With *zsh* recursive globbing is default.

<sup>2</sup> rsync  version v3.2.3  protocol version 31 on Linux.

### Possibility 2

Only using rsync's filter rules you need:

a. To include all `bin` dirs in the `top_dir` hierarchy:

```
rsync -av -m --include='**/' --include='**/bin/**' --exclude='*' top_dir/ destination_path
```

The first `include` rule might not be obvious<sup>3</sup> but guarantees that all directories (note the trailing `/`) are searched, the second adds everything in `bin` directories, and the `exclude` rule excludes everything else. `-m` makes sure that empty directories are not copied.

b. To include only one level below the project dir:

```
rsync -av -m  --include='/*/' --include='/*/bin/***' --exclude='*' top_dir/ destination_path
```

Using `***` syntax of rsync >= 2.6.7. The leading `/` in the patterns represent `top_dir`, otherwise the patterns are matched against the *end* of the file path.

---

<sup>3</sup> Search for `/some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found` in `man rsync`

Comment: Possibility 1 worked for me, although I had to change ** to *, since there are nested bin directories I don't want to include - see the updated source tree above. I'm hoping to get possibility 2 to work, since although I have zsh, this will probably get used by others who don't have zsh or a new enough version of bash. Unfortunately, the include/exclude filter expressions you provided seem to match everything, at least with v2.6.9 of rsync.

Comment: Actually, the Possibility 2 filter expressions are closer than I realized. They were including all of the directories, but not the files within the non-bin dirs. If I add -m, it's almost right. The command `rsync -avm --include='**/' --include='**/bin/**' --exclude='*' top_dir/ dest_dir` still includes the nested bin dir. Even if I change the second pattern to `'*/bin/**'` or `'bin/**'`, it still picks up the nested bin dir.

Comment: @MattPassell Then I would definitively use Poss. 1. The `*` should work in _every_ Un*x shell used today. I updated my answer with appropriate rsync rule, too.

Comment: @XavierStuvw: Thanks for your language polishing, however I reverted the explanaition of `-R` as I double-checked with my version (which I included now in the answer) that `-R` (capital R) means _relative_, small `-r` is _recursive_. What version/OS are you using?

Comment: My apologies for the blunder. You are absolutely right @mpy and my wires had to be completely crossed. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude all `src` directories using `--exclude src/`

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't made it clear that there are other directories and files there. I've edited the file tree to clarify that.